# inner join and update

Tags: sql

I have a table1 as below

```
user_ID country  status  role
-------- ------ ------- -----
keshav   SG        Active  Admin
Bargav   IN        Active  Subuser
Sanvi     GB       Active   subuser
yellin    CN       Active    subuser
```

I have another table stage_table as below

```
user_ID  country   role 
-------  -------  ------
keshav     SG      Admin
Sanvi      GB      subuser
Manav      IN      subuser
```

I want to update table1 based on stage_table. As you can see stage_table doesnot have Bargav record so I want to update table1 Bargav row with status as "InActive"  and Manav entry is new so update it as it is with status as "Active". Thus table1 should be as below

```
user_ID  country  status Role 
-------  -------  ------  -----
keshav   SG        Active  Admin
Bargav   IN        InActive  Subuser
Sanvi     GB       Active   subuser
yellin    CN       Active    subuser
Manav     In       Active    subuser
```

I am thinking of using an inner join as below, is this correct? I am not getting the desired result.. because I don't know how to do merge and update simultaneously

```
select * 
from table1 
inner join stage_table on table1.user_ID = stage_table.user_ID 
                       and (update table.status ="InActive" 
                            where table1.user_Id != stage_table.user_ID)
```

Please help.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Only tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? PostgreSQL?

Comment: mysql sqlite mariadb were in the original question. In general it is strongly recommended to only add the database you need the query for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL/Mariadb and (I think) SQLite will use a traditional SQL construct such as the following where you need to do the insert and the update as seperate queries:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (user_ID, country, status, role)
SELECT t2.user_ID, t2.country,'Active' as Status, t2.role 
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
WHERE t1.user_id IS NULL
;

UPDATE  table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
SET t1.status = CASE WHEN t2.user_id IS NULL THEN 'InActive' ELSE 'Active' END
;
```

Comment: how to insert it if user_ID is primary key ? its throwing exception since user_id is primary ..if I remove primary key it works but duplicate entries for user_ID will be there

Comment: If the user_id is already present in table1 it should not insert **(where t1.user_id is null)**  You may have implemented differently to what I intended. Often it is easier for all parties if we use real table names.

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL Server you can use following two queries for Update and Insert respectively --

```
-- For Update
UPDATE T1
SET T1.[STATUS] = (
    CASE 
        WHEN T2.[USER_ID] IS NULL
            THEN 'INACTIVE'
        ELSE T1.[STATUS]
        END
    )
FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN STAGE_TABLE T2 ON T1.[USER_ID] = T2.[USER_ID];

-- For Insert
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (
    [USER_ID]
    ,COUNTRY
    ,[STATUS]
    ,[ROLE]
    )
SELECT T2.[USER_ID]
    ,T2.COUNTRY
    ,'Active'
    ,T2.[ROLE]
FROM TABLE1 T1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN STAGE_TABLE T2 ON T1.[USER_ID] = T2.[USER_ID]
WHERE T1.[USER_ID] IS NULL;
```